# changing the content of .txt file - on browsing file

Tags: javascript, file

I want to draw structure of some chemicals based on values in a log file . So I write a javascript for drawing and it works for predefined x,y,z coordinates value

.txt file contain [image]

its 5th,6th,7th indicates x,y,z coordinates value.

log file contain following fields
[image: log file content]

is there is any way to browse a file from user and accept those value in 5th,6th,7th field of .txt file.

Comment: have a look at this- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: @xavy above link is very usefull for me.... But I want to read only x,y,z coordinates values in log file. and this value is taken in 5th,6th,7th field of .txt file

Answer (score 0):

To get the file uploaded check out kk anu's answer.

Once you have the file in access and can read it, it's a straight forward iteration of each line.

```
var linesFromFile= file.split(/[ ,]+/);

linesFromFile.forEach(function(entry)
{
    var parsedFloat = parseFloat(entry);

    if(parsedFloat === Number(parsedFloat)  && parsedFloat%1!==0){
        // do something with the parsed float
    }
});
```

You have to adapt the code for your needs, but this is basically the function to go with.